# Lottery Javascript cant clear the array

Tags: javascript

So I'm making a simulation of the lottery. I generate 6 numbers between 0 and 40 and show them in the html id 'generated'. My problem is that if I click a second time on 'generate' (in my html page), the previous generated numbers are still a part of the array and still show up. Does anybody know how to clear the array when pushed on the button multiple times?

This is my Javascript code:

```
'use strict';
function generatenumbers(){
    let number = [];
    let i;
    i=0;
    for(i= 0; i <= 5; i++){
        number[i] = Math.floor(Math.random()*40);
    }
    i = 0;
    for(i=0; i<= number.length - 1; i++){
        let node = document.createElement("LI");
        let textnode = document.createTextNode(number[i]);
        node.appendChild(textnode);
        document.getElementById("generated").appendChild(node);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to remove the previously appended children then add new ones.

```
var list = document.getElementById("generated"); 
list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]); // for removing first child only

//for removing all children
  var list = document.getElementById("genrated");
  while (list.firstChild) {
    list.removeChild(list.firstChild);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't want to clear the array...you want to clear the document.getElementById("generated") element before you call the loop, that way, there will always be 6 LI elements at the end of the function.

```
document.getElementById("generated").innerHTML = ""; // clear the element

for(i=0; i<= number.length - 1; i++){
    let node = document.createElement("LI");
    let textnode = document.createTextNode(number[i]);
    node.appendChild(textnode);
    document.getElementById("generated").appendChild(node);
}
```